# Python: Print only when the sum is not zero

Tags: python

If the sum of mult_list or non_mult_list is equal to zero, I don't want it print 0 out as below, it doesn't need to print anything. What should I add to restrict this situation?

Here is my code

```
n , m = map(int, input().split()) 
num_list = list(map(int,input().split()))

mult_list=[]
non_mult_list=[]
if m >= 2 and m <= 9:
    for i in (num_list)[:n]:
        if i%m == 0:
            mult_list.append(i)
        
    for j in (num_list)[:n]:
        if j%m != 0:
            non_mult_list.append(j)

print (sum(mult_list))
print (sum(non_mult_list))
```

Here is my input:

2 9

5 7

Then its output:

0

12

Comment: `if-else` should work here.

Comment: what if the sum of only one list is zero.

Comment: I tried to add else then break before but it still print 0, could u please teach me what should I add after else: ? Thanks

Comment: for this question, I hope the answer be like 12 only, just print the non zero answer

Comment: Try my code now;.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
n , m = map(int, input().split()) 
num_list = list(map(int,input().split()))

mult_list=[]
non_mult_list=[]
if m >= 2 and m <= 9:
    for i in (num_list)[:n]:
        if i%m == 0:
            mult_list.append(i)
        
    for j in (num_list)[:n]:
        if j%m != 0:
            non_mult_list.append(j)
sum_mult_list = sum(mult_list)
sum_non_mult_list = sum(non_mult_list)
if sum_mult_list: # edited
    print(sum_mult_list)
if sum_non_mult_list: #edited
    print(sum_non_mult_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
if sum(mult_list) != 0:
    print(sum(mult_list))

if sum(non_mult_list) != 0:
    print(sum(non_mult_list))
```

Comment: Calling the sum function two times is not a good practice, Alternate you can make a variable bro.